# Custom Magento API - Resource Path is not Callable

Tags: magento-1.9, api, custom, module, web-services

I am trying to create custom api in magento

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172197/magento-api-publish-a-new-method-in-soap-v2/12258728#12258728?newreg=18f107c4fd89455ebd2b300992cf8fae

I am getting Below 2 errors

1. While calling webservice

> EXCEPTION=SoapFault exception: [4] Resource path is not callable. in D:\xampp\htdocs*****\CustomApiCaller.php:22 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs****\CustomApiCaller.php(22): SoapClient->__call('folderMyapimeth...', Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs*****\CustomApiCaller.php(22): SoapClient->folderMyapimethod('2ac263f18e06b89...', NULL) #2 {main}

2. While browsing Edit role page form back end

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mymodule_Helper_Data' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs*****\app\Mage.php on line 547

Below are my files

### Folder Structute

[image]

### MyCompany_MyModule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

### Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <MyModule>
                <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model</class>
            </MyModule>
        </models>
        <!--<helpers>
        <MyModule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
        </MyModule>
        </helpers>-->
    </global>
</config>
```

Note - Here i tried both(without commenting helpers node also but not luck.

### Api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <Mymodule>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <mymodule_folder translate="title" module="mymodule">
                <title>mymodule</title>
                <model>mymodule/folder_api</model>
                <acl>mymodule/folder</acl>
                <methods>                    
                    <myapimethod translate="title" module="mymodule">
                        <title>myapimethod</title>
                        <acl>mymodule/folder/myapimethod</acl>
                    </myapimethod> 
                </methods>
            </mymodule_folder>
        </resources>
        <resources_alias>
            <folder>mymodule_folder</folder>
         </resources_alias>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <folder>folder</folder>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <mymodule translate="title" module="mymodule">
                    <title>mymodule</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <folder translate="title" module="mymodule">
                        <title>Folder</title>
                        <sort_order>2000</sort_order>                    
                         <myapimethod translate="title" module="mymodule">
                            <title>myapimethod</title>
                        </myapimethod>  
                    </folder>
             </mymodule>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

### wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
        <types>
            <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
                <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </schema>
        </types>
        <message name="folderMyapimethodRequest">
            <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
            <part name="message" type="xsd:string" />
        </message>
        <message name="folderMyapimethodResponse">
            <part name="result" type="xsd:string" />
        </message>
        <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
            <operation name="folderMyapimethod">
                <documentation>this is an example of api method...</documentation>
                <input message="typens:folderMyapimethodRequest" />
                <output message="typens:folderMyapimethodResponse" />
            </operation>
        </portType>
        <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
            <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
            <operation name="folderMyapimethod">
                <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
                <input>
                    <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
                </output>
            </operation>
        </binding>
        <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
            <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
                <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
            </port>
        </service>
    </definitions>
```

### wsi.xml

```
<wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="folderMyapimethod">
        <wsdl:documentation>Retrieve list of deal</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:input message="typens:folderMyapimethodRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="typens:folderMyapimethodResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="folderMyapimethod">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
        <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Note - I also tried bu not using wsi.xml file but not luck because compliance is set to no in back end.

### Api.php ##

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Folder_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{        
        public function myapimethod( $message)
        {
            return "This is the message: ".$message;
        }
}
```

### V2.php ##

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Folder_Api_V2 extends Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Folder_Api
{   

}
```

Note - Also tried including helper folder and Data.php file and referring in config.xml but still not luck.

Can someone please check what I am missing here....

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks
Siddharth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to resolve issue....After much head scratching and comparing my files back and forth with core api files

First as you said, I have updated all config files with exactly same name(considering case senstivity) of files/folders.

Still i was getting same error, not sure how but Then I realized that a closing global tab .. was missing in config.xml file :( :(

And bang it worked liked charm....Thanks

Let me know if anybody needs updated files.

[Edit] - Missed to mention - also renamed helper folder and reffered it in config.xml, this actually i tried before but didn't worked then...may be it worked because of putting names exactly same.

Thanks
Siddharth

Answer (score 3):

I can not help you with the "resource path is not callable" issue, but I would assume that it has something to do with you developing in a local XAMPP environment.

For the problem with the helper that is not found:

You have to un-comment the helper-classification in your config.xml and rename the "Helperasdasd"-folter to "Helper"; in there must lay a file called Data.php with the class declaration:

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data {}
```

This is enough for the contents of this file.

Also, in the api.xml file, everywhere you use `module="mymodule"`, update this to exactly the name of the helper-config-path in the config.xml; you are on Windows I guess, and thus it may not be case sensitive. on every other system, it is.
Additionally, I don't believe Windows is officially supported my Magento.